# Porque el comando sdkmanager --list no me regresa los api levels en offline?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity, sdk

tengo un problemita, cuando estoy trabajando online el comando:

> `sdkmanager --list`

me regresa las versiones de api correctamente (desde la 16 hasta la 28) pero cuando no estoy en linea no me regresa las versiones de api y no puedo compilar mi proyecto en unity.

Unity usa el mismo comando para setear el api level mínimo y el preferido para la app en android, alguien sabe ¿porque no se me guardan esos datos en mi pc? antes no daba ese problema.

Comment: ¿a que te refieres estar offline?

Comment: cuando estoy desconectado de internet bro, en mi trabajo tengo internet pero en mi apartamento no jejeje y trabajo en mis proyectos en mi apartamento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**La razón por la cual no funciona este comando sin conexión, es porque `sdkmanager --list` necesita revisar si existen actualizaciones disponibles**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Te recomiendo realizar la consulta y actualización desde Android Studio:

> [Android sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html#usage) : sdkmanager es una herramienta de línea de
>   comandos que te permite ver, instalar, actualizar y desinstalar
>   paquetes para el SDK de Android. Si estás usando Android Studio,
>   entonces no necesitas usar esta herramienta y, en su lugar, puedes
>   administrar tus paquetes de SDK desde el IDE.
>
> La herramienta sdkmanager se proporciona en el paquete de Herramientas
>   del SDK de Android (25.2.3 y versiones posteriores) y se ubica en
>   android_sdk/tools/bin/.

Comment: te entiendo pero anteriormente no me daba ese problema en una version vieja de unity, por eso no entiendo que sucede, gracias por la ayuda!